# NetSuite Countries With States In Addresses

Tags: netsuite

NetSuite, out of the box, comes with the knowledge that several countries - the US, China, Australia, etc. - have states/provinces. In the standard Address form, if you chose one of those countries, rather than giving you a free-form text field in which to enter the state, it gives you a list of the states it knows about based on the country.

You can add to the list of states in a given country via Setup=>Company=>States/Provinces/Counties. If you add a state to one of the countries that NetSuite knows have states, it'll appear in the list of states for that country when you choose the country in the standard Address form.

In the same place at Setup=>Company=>States/Provinces/Counties you can add a new country and specify its states, just like it comes out of the box with US, China, etc. But when you do that and then, in the standard Address form, select that new country, it doesn't give you the list of that country's states - it just gives you the standard free-form text field. But we want it to show the list of states in that country and prevent free-form entry, just like it does out of the box with, say, the US?

My question is - how do I tell NetSuite to use the defined states for the new country in the Address form and not allow free-form text entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I observed in my test account: if there is only state/province defined for the country, the free-form entry is still shown in the address form. If there are at least two states, the dropdown is shown.

Comment: Jala, if we weren't online and it wasn't hugely inappropriate and, given this COVID-19 situation, dangerous to boot, I would kiss you. I didn't even think to try it with more than one state but, as you say, the extra one did it. You've solved my problem and I will be eternally grateful.